# Why '$p' appears at the first line of vim in iterm?

Tags: macos, vim, xterm, iterm2

I'm using Mac OS 10.13.4.

**iTerm2 Version** is Build 2.1.1

**Vim Version** is
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com

And I Installed the **Vundle plugin**

And when I open vim in iTerm2 with oh-my-zsh, the $p appears at the first line.
[image]

It doesn't appear with Terminal.app of Apple?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no code here. This is not a programming question. Try https://superuser.com/?

Comment: Actually it's a question about escape sequences, which is topical.  vi.SE won't offer a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

vim is assuming that iTerm2 is xterm (not a good assumption), and attempting to determine the state of the [**`cursorBlink`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:cursorBlink) resource by sending an escape sequence containing **`$p`** which iTerm2 does not handle properly (see [source-code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1f8495cf48888ff3a8ab3d0eb22db92389191a60/src/term.c#L863) for vim for the escape sequence, and also where it [uses the feature](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1f8495cf48888ff3a8ab3d0eb22db92389191a60/src/term.c#L4697)).  While vim starts with the `TERM` setting (i.e., "xterm"), it does make a few checks to exclude things like gnome-terminal as noted in the source code comment.  But iTerm2 happens to fool vim in this case.  So the result goes to the screen.

In *[XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)* that is documented like this:

```
CSI ? Ps$ p
          Request DEC private mode (DECRQM).  For VT300 and up, reply is
            CSI ? Ps; Pm$ y
          where Ps is the mode number as in DECSET/DECSET, Pm is the
          mode value as in the ANSI DECRQM.
          Two private modes are read-only (i.e., 1 3  and 1 4 ), pro-
          vided only for reporting their values using this control
          sequence.  They correspond to the resources cursorBlink and
          cursorBlinkXOR.
```

Although vim is fooled here, the problem is due to iTerm2, for which you've probably set the `TERM` environment variable to `xterm-256color`, or something like that.  It doesn't match iTerm2's behavior very well (the function keys don't match up, etc).  ncurses provides a better one.  But out-of-the-box MacOS has a terminal database that's about ten years old, and lacks that entry.  To get a good terminal database (i.e., one where you could set `TERM` to [**`iterm2`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-iterm2)), you could do that with MacPorts or home-brew.

Running infocmp to get a measure of the differences between the (correct) **`iterm2`** entry and **`linux`**, **`xterm-256color`** shows that

- it's actually closer to **`nsterm-256color`** (a *correct* entry for Terminal.app which Apple doesn't provide) with 38 lines of difference,
- next closest **`linux`** with 76 lines and
- still further away from **`xterm-256color`** with 94 lines.

The feature that's missing or mis-implemented in iTerm2 isn't in the terminal description: it's a special feature that vim has to guess about.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, this $p is due to vim sending a control sequence for a cursor blink request. In your .vimrc, you can turn off the cursor blink request by clearing the t_RC terminal option. I wrapped this in a conditional which turns it off only for 256 color terminals.

```
if &term =~ '256color'
  set t_RC=
endif
```

Comment: However, `t_RC` should only have been set if (a) it read that from a terminal description, or (b) from the user's local configuration.  Since there aren't any standard terminal descriptions with `RC` (because it means something entirely different in *termcap*), it sounds like (b) was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the terminal explicitly to `linux` solved it for me:

`export TERM=linux`

Answer (score -1):

The **p means** **print**, which is the command the range is being given to, and yes.. it displays to you what is in that range.

In **vim** you can look at **:help :range and :help :print** to find out more about how this works. These types of ranges are also used by **sed and other editors**.

They probably used the **1,$ terminology** in the tutorial to be explicit, but note that you can also use **%** as its equivalent. Thus, **%p** will also print all the lines in the file.

Comment: So how can I remove these chars? I don't want vim to show them every time I open it. Type `vim -u NONE` to use vim is a solution, however it is inconvenient